# How to make #[should_panic(expected = ...)] match exactly

Tags: testing, rust

Lets say I have the following test:

```rust
#[test]
#[should_panic(expected = "foo panic message")]
fn foo_test() {
    foo()
}
```

But it succeeds even if the panic message has additional characters, e.g. `"    foo panic message"`

Is there a way to make this test only succeed if the panic message matches the expected string **exactly**, instead of when the message only contains the expected string?

Comment: [Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-01-writing-tests.html) : _To make `should_panic` tests more precise, we can add an optional `expected` parameter to the `should_panic` attribute. The test harness will make sure that the failure message **contains** the provided text_ This means you need a work around like putting message id to the message as  prefix or suffix

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `#[should_panic]` that way but you can catch any<sup>1</sup> panics and assert that the message matches what you expect yourself:

```rust
use std::panic::{AssertUnwindSafe, catch_unwind};
#[test]
fn should_panic() {
    let msg = catch_unwind(AssertUnwindSafe(|| {
        panic!(" foo panic message");
    }));

    assert_eq!("foo panic message", *msg.unwrap_err().downcast_ref::<&str>().unwrap());
}
```

The catch is that you have to know the exact type(s) the expected message can have (usually `String` or `&str` but can be anything) to be able to `downcast` it to compare it.

---

<sup>1: as the name suggests `catch_unwind` only catches unwiniding, if for any reason your process is aborted, this will not work.</sup>

Comment: It would be nice if this function can be converted to some kind of wrapper function to run test logic then catch the panic, since std is implemented this way([Catch](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/70adb4e5b4c8f8bde4ade0edcb0435ff7bf31281/library/test/src/lib.rs#L679) then [Downcast](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/70adb4e5b4c8f8bde4ade0edcb0435ff7bf31281/library/test/src/test_result.rs#L40) ) it can provide a chance to override this behavior in a cleaner way.